# Reading named pipe does not flush it

Tags: c++, linux, named-pipes

This is my first test on using unix named pipes. Below is a simple example which tries to read a given pipe every second and, on success, outputs "triggered" to stdout. Using a bash script I can write that value to the pipe which is read by the program as expected.

The problem is, that the program keeps reading the value on every following loop although it is only written once to the pipe. Every tutorial I could find tells me, everything which is read from the pipe is basically removed and if one wants to flush a pipe simply read everything. But the program below keeps outputting the value over and over without new input.

**main.cpp**

```cpp
// std
#include <iostream>
// unix
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    // create named pipe
    mkfifo("/tmp/alarm_motion", 0666);

    for(;;){

        int fifo = open("/tmp/alarm_motion", O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
        char temp[sizeof(int)];
        int st = read(fifo, temp, sizeof(temp));
        if(st == 0){
            int res = atoi(temp);
            std::cout << "fifo" << res;
            if(res == 1){
                std::cout << " -> triggered";
                    close(fifo);
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

**test.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
pipe=/tmp/alarm_motion
echo 1 > $pipe
```

If I compile the program, start it, and execute the script after a few cycles, I receive the output below

**sample output**

```
fifo0
fifo0
fifo0
fifo0
fifo0
fifo0
fifo1 -> triggered
fifo1 -> triggered
fifo1 -> triggered
fifo1 -> triggered
fifo1 -> triggered
fifo1 -> triggered
```

while I would expect the following output

**desired output**

```
fifo0
fifo0
fifo0
fifo0
fifo0
fifo0
fifo1 -> triggered
fifo0
fifo0
fifo0
fifo0
fifo0
```

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong here?

*g++ (Raspbian 4.9.2-10) on Raspbian 8*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some serious flaws in your program:

- An integer in text form may be *much* larger than the size of an `int`. For example the text `"12345678"` is *eight* bytes (not including string terminator!) which should be compared to the usual size of `4` for `sizeof(int)`.
- Nothing says that the data you read will be zero-terminated. That means all functions that treat the data you read as a zero-terminated string (like e.g. `atoi`) will not work reliably.
- The `read` function returns `0` when the pipe has been *closed* by the other end. Which means the data you attempt to use doesn't really exist. The `read` call (after returning `0`) haven't actually read anything.
- You have a serious resource leak, as you `open` the pipe over and over again without closing it.
- You have no error handling what so ever.

Finally, that you seem to be reading the same data over and over is probably because of how the compiler have implemented your `temp` array. It simply reuses the same memory. Since you just continue to loop over and over again you will see the same data over and over again since the location of the array is the same and the compiler (or your program) have cleared the memory in any way in between. The pipe is flushed, your memory contents is not.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive input. The posted code is only a small sample  test and therefore all of the error handling etc. is removed from it. But the last point, combined with the answer by EJP helped me solving it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
int st = read(fifo, temp, sizeof(temp));
```

This returns -1 on error, zero at end of stream, or a positive integer denoting the number of bytes that have been transferred.

Therefore this:

```
    if(st == 0){
        int res = atoi(temp);
        std::cout << "fifo" << res;
        if(res == 1){
            std::cout << " -> triggered";
                close(fifo);
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
```

makes no sense. This block is what you should do if `st` is *positive.* If it is zero you should close the pipe and exit the loop; if it is -1 you should call `perror()`, close the pipe, and exit the loop.

At present you are reading *until* end of stream, then printing the last thing you received, forever.

You should also open the pipe prior to the loop. You can also get rid of the `sleep()`. The `read()` will block while no data is available.

Comment: Thank you, this and the answer by Some programmer dude helped solving the issue, since his last point covers the main issue I'll accept his although both have been equally helpful.